# Get result from many tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, multiple-tables

I have a few tables wich I need to get results from into one query.

This is how I make it today.

```
$sql="select * from structure 
a, audio b where a.id=b.id_parent and b.published=1 order by b.data desc";
```

This gives me a list of audio.
What I need to do is get responses from many tables. As you can see I am calling two tables structure and audio. I need to get results from structure, audio, vector and photos. Any clues how I would do this?

Comment: using sql join in the query should help if i understood it right..

Comment: either you can use joins or the way you are doing, only thing you need to put those tables in relation WRT associated columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have **relationship** in those tables then you can use **joins** to get data from multiple table

```
select * from structure 
a inner join 
audio b on a.id=b.id_parent where b.published=1 order by b.data desc
```

**edited** as per comment from user

you can do nesting of inner join for example

```
    SELECT DISTINCTROW 
       tblChippingSystems.Manufacturer_ID
     , tblChippingSystems.Chippingcounter
     , tblManufacturer.ManufacturerDesc
     , tblChippingSystems.Customer_ID 
  FROM ( tblChippingSystems 
INNER
  JOIN tblManufacturer 
    ON tblChippingSystems.Manufacturer_ID 
     = tblManufacturer.Manufacturer_ID )
INNER
  JOIN tblModel 
    ON tblChippingSystems.Model_ID = tblModel.Model_ID
 WHERE tblChippingSystems.Customer_ID =   k
ORDER 
    BY tblChippingSystems.Manufacturer_ID DESC
```

> but make sure that you have proper reference between these tables and
>   double check your  resulted data

Comment: How would I join the other tables from that? I need to join the other tables as well but how?

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create a view in the database that is based on the joined query. That way, your program just need to knwo to query from that view.

You will still need to writ the join SQL, but at least after it is done, it will be transparent to the rest of the coding.